# Newton method to find $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}$

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

What function should I use to find $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}$ without using division?

Comment: Is this from a contest?  It's surprising that such a question would show up twice like this.

Comment: This is a pretty classic textbook problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Try:

$$f(x) = x^2 - \dfrac{1}{a} = 0$$

Comment: +1 I think this is an answer rather than a hint but a better answer than mine either way for a number of reasons.... but I can trump you with $f(x)=ax^2-1$!

Comment: Actually, they are the same, just multiply through by $a$. :-)

Comment: I know this but in the same way that your answer is better than mine, $ax^2-1$ is better than yours :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** What do you have to do to $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}$ to get $0$?

How about square it to get $\displaystyle \frac{1}{a}$, then invert it to get $a$ and then take away $a$ to get zero.

What function does that?

Comment: Not quite but almost. What you have written above is true for all (strictly) positive $a$. What the Newton Method does is approximate roots. What your statement above shows is that $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}$ is a root of $\displaystyle f(x)=x^{-2}-a=\frac{1}{x^2}-a$...